# No object exists at the desired reference

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to get an image from the storage and use the url for a default profile picture but i am getting this error.

> firebase_storage/object-not-found No object exists at the desired reference.

[image]

This is my code.

```
void authenticateStudent() async {
    User? currentStudent;
    final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    await firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: umailController.text.trim(),
      password: passwordController.text.trim(),
    )
        .then((auth) {
      currentStudent = auth.user;
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
    if (currentStudent != null) { 
FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('profile')
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) {
        imageUrl = url;
      });
saveDataToFirestore(currentStudent!).then((value) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        print("User added successfully");
      });
    }
  }

Future saveDataToFirestore(User currentStudent) async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("students")
        .doc(currentStudent.uid)
        .set({
      "studentUID": currentStudent.uid,
      "fname": fnameController.text.trim(),
      "lname": lnameController.text.trim(),
      "Mobile": phoneController.text.trim(),
      "Program": selectedProgram,
      "student_id": studentidController.text.trim(),
      "cohort": selectedCohort,
      "umail": currentStudent.email,
      "profilepicture": imageUrl,
      "active": active,
      "status": status
    });
  }
```

The database is structured like this

This is my code.

```
void authenticateStudent() async {
    User? currentStudent;
    final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    await firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: umailController.text.trim(),
      password: passwordController.text.trim(),
    )
        .then((auth) {
      currentStudent = auth.user;
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
    if (currentStudent != null) { 
FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('profile')
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) {
        imageUrl = url;
      });
saveDataToFirestore(currentStudent!).then((value) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        print("User added successfully");
      });
    }
  }

Future saveDataToFirestore(User currentStudent) async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("students")
        .doc(currentStudent.uid)
        .set({
      "studentUID": currentStudent.uid,
      "fname": fnameController.text.trim(),
      "lname": lnameController.text.trim(),
      "Mobile": phoneController.text.trim(),
      "Program": selectedProgram,
      "student_id": studentidController.text.trim(),
      "cohort": selectedCohort,
      "umail": currentStudent.email,
      "profilepicture": imageUrl,
      "active": active,
      "status": status
    });
  }
```

The database is structured like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code says:

```
FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('profile')
      .getDownloadURL()
```

But in the screenshot, the file is called `profile.png`. The path must match completely and exactly, so:

```
FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('profile.png')
      .getDownloadURL()
```

Comment: Getting the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Does it make sense why this change is needed though? If it still doesn't work after this change, check if there are other mismatches in the path or in the configured project.